# Display text on thumbnail image WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am currenty creating a small webshop for myself in wordpress with woocommerce.

On the productpage (archive) thumbnails are shown with prices below and links below.

However, I would like to have the "new" text of the product shown on the thumbnail image. I already tried this below and it shows New! above the thumbnail image.

My question is: **How can I display text on the thumbnail image of WooCommerce instead of above?**

[Advance Custom fields question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219428/custom-text-label-on-woocommerce-shop-thumbnail-images)

Comment: where is your link ??

Comment: I am currently experimenting on localhost. I use this theme:
https://foodiepro.com/shop/

Comment: Could you please show me screenshot of what you want

Comment: You can use this(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219428/custom-text-label-on-woocommerce-shop-thumbnail-images) method and you need to write css for display text on image.

Comment: this is an example: https://imgur.com/a/nJJgSUb

Comment: Or You can Try This Plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-product-stickers-for-woocommerce/